# WPF UI Style partially frozen in a wrong state after Command Execution

Tags: c#, wpf, command

another day, another problem. Honestly, it would be rather boring if this ever stopped, wouldn't it?

EDIT : Seems all of the background-information is obsolete. Here's the boiled down version:
My Command class rigs up CanExecuteChanged with the CommandManagers RequerySuggested event (as described here : [WPF Custom ICommand implementation and the CanExecuteChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768301/)).

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

In my case, the CommandManager fails to suggest a requery where it would be of some importance. Now I have to bypass this and force it to requery. Does anybody know how to do this?

**Another Edit:** I've tried really many things now (changing my command logic, removing control template and style), and still get stuck on this. I can't reproduce the problem in an isolated sandbox scenario, though. I really think I am suffering from a bug here, since the Button's behaviour is inconsistent with its looks, even if the Style is boiled down to the following :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="CertificateActionButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CertificateActionButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I unfocus and then focus the window again, Coherence is restored - the button the looks as inactive as it is.

**Update :** Since I haven't been able to reproduce this issue, i close this question.
The only answer it has received was a good one, but after having edited the question so many times, q & a don't really seem related any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx).

> The CommandManager only pays attention
>   to certain conditions in determining
>   when the command target has changed,
>   such as change in keyboard focus. In
>   situations where the CommandManager
>   does not sufficiently determine a
>   change in conditions that cause a
>   command to not be able to execute,
>   InvalidateRequerySuggested can be
>   called to force the CommandManager to
>   raise the RequerySuggested event.

also from the notes:

> It should be noted, that if you are
>   using async calls, then the
>   CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
>   should be called from the main thread,
>   as any command listeners will be on
>   the UI thread. (Use a Dispatcher and call CheckAccess())

Comment: Thanks mark, I think this would have worked if it weren't a completely different issue that was bothering me. Please see my edits above for updates.