# DataGrid in WPF using VisualStudio C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have 3 `TexBox`es,`Button`s and `DataGrid` in my window. when I enter the data into the `TextBox` and click on the button it should add into the `DataGrid` .I need a code for how to add, delete and get data. I'm new to wpf please help me with the code.
This is my Xaml code

```
  <Window x:Class="simpledatagrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="IDDATA" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid  >
    <DataGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dgsample" Margin="200,10,10,75"></DataGrid>

    <Label  Content="ID :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="27"/>
    <Label  Content="Name :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="48"/>
    <Label  Content="Salary :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="47"/>

    <TextBox Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,10,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <TextBox Name="tb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,60,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <TextBox Name="tb3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,110,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

    <Button Content="Get" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Get_Click" />
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Add_Click" />
    <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,270,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Delete_Click" />
</Grid>
```

This is my .cs code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         List<User> users = new List<User>();
                    users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10 });
                    users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20 });
                    users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30 });

                    dgsample.ItemsSource = users;
            }

    private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , you can use ObservableCollection instead of List. because ObservableCollection has INotifyCollectionChanged defaultly. ObservableCollection is TwoWayBinding.

```
ObservableCollection<User> users = new  ObservableCollection<User>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

                users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10 });
                users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20 });
                users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30 });

                dgsample.ItemsSource = users;
}

private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.tb1.Text != string.Empty) { User currentUser = users.Single(select => select.Id == Int32.Parse(this.tb1.Text)); this.tb2.Text = currentUser.Name; this.tb3.Text = currentUser.Salary; } 
}

private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      users.Add(new User() { Id = 105, Name = "gin5", Salary = 100 });
}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   users.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: this.tb3.Text = currentUser.Salary.ToString();

Comment: can u expalin the code that u have written for the get_click event please

Comment: from the collection(users), i compare the Id value with tb1 TextBox, and get the correct index and assign to new User instance.finally get the the value from that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Define User class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(int id, string name, int salary)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Then in your MainWindow.xaml.cs file change your List to ObservableCollection (you will need to add;

`using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` // EDIT

and then:

```
ObservableCollection<User> users;

public MainWindow()
{
    users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10 });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20 });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30 });

    InitializeComponent();
    dgsample.ItemsSource = users;
}


private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    users.Add(new User(){Id = Int.Parse(tb1.Text), Name = tb2.Text, Salary = Int.Parse(tb3.Text)});
}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    users.RemoveAt(dgSample.SelectedIndex);
}

// you can get what you need just selected proper User proprety
private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(( (User)dgSample.Items[dgSample.SelectedIndex]).Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a `ObservableCollection` property to be set a `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid` and update it when you want to add/delete any item from `DataGrid`. Updating the Collection will update the datagrid

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Users = new ObservableCollection<User>;
            Users.Add(new User() {Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10});
            Users.Add(new User() {Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20});
            Users.Add(new User() {Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30});

            dgsample.ItemsSource = Users;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Users.Add(new User() {Id = int.Parse(tb1.Text), Name = tb2.Text, Salary = tb3.Text});
        }
```

Also, as a suggestion, the add/delete functionality is inbuild in `DataGrid`, setting  `CanUserAddRows` and `CanUserDeleteRows` to true allows user to add item directly into the `DataGrid`, so you may not need your textboxes and button to add/delete

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"></DataGrid>
```

Comment: what is the error? you will need to add the namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel

Comment: Error The name 'users' does not exist in the current context i'm getting this

Comment: you dont have 'users' property it is 'Users'...change it

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to WPF you should start by doing things the [WPF way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681352/transitioning-from-windows-forms-to-wpf/15684569#15684569). In WPF you should manipulate your data which is binded to the UI, instead of manipulating the UI directly. This design pattern is known as [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

In your case, you will have a class (known as the *ViewModel*) which will contain the collection of your `User` items (known as the *Model*).

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
                users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10 });
                users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20 });
                users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30 });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In your `MainWindow` (known as the *View*) code-behind all you should do is set it's `DataContext` as the `MainWindowViewModel`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

In the window itself, bind the collection to the `Users` propery in your *ViewModel*

```
 <DataGrid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dgsample" Margin="200,10,10,75" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"></DataGrid>
```

As for your `TextBox`es, as they are intended to crate a new `User`, you can have another `User` property on your *ViewModel*

```
public User NewUser { get; set; }
```

And bind them to their matching properties in your `User` class

```
<TextBox Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,10,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=NewUser.Id}"/>
<TextBox Name="tb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,60,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=NewUser.Name}"/>
<TextBox Name="tb3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,110,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=NewUser.Salary}"/>
```

After adding the new `User`, clear it's properties.

As for your buttons, they should communicate with the *ViewModel* via [Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838884/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf), which then only manipulate the collection itself using the simple [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) and [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413.aspx) methods it implements. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF)

Hope this helps

Comment: Error The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error The name 'users' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Add the following using statement `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`

Comment: did you define `Users` as a public property in your *ViewModel*? where are you trying to access it from?

Comment: @user2889489 Update your question with the updated code and the error's you are getting. We can't help you without understanding what you are doing ...

Comment: @user2889489 I don't think you understand me. Please edit your question and post your newest code so I can help you