# WPF: Mouse double click on Image using interaction

Tags: wpf, double-click

I'm trying to use interaction features to achieve mouse double click on standard Image control. The Image control is on UserControl and method that should handle mouse double click is on view model. The code is as following:

1) UserControl:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                  
            Name="SelectedListView">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="None">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="DblClick" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

3) View model:

```
public void DblClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Double click!");
}
```

But, it doesn't work.

UPDATE:

I did this, but it doesn't work:

1) XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                  
            Name="SelectedListView">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}">
                    <Image.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"/>
                    </Image.InputBindings>
                </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

2) View model:

```
public DelegateCommand MouseDoubleClickCommand { get; private set; }
```

In constructor:

```
MouseDoubleClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(DblClick);
```

And added method:

```
public void DblClick()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Double click!");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Image class has no `MouseDoubleClick` event but you could use an `InputBinding` that binds to an `ICommand` property:

```
<Image Source="pic.png">
    <Image.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"/>
    </Image.InputBindings>
</Image>
```

---

```
public ICommand MouseDoubleClickCommand { get; } = new DelegateCommand<object>(obj => { MessageBox.Show(""); });
```

You will need to provide an implementation of the `ICommand` interface or use someone else's. The `DelegateCommand<T>` class is available in Prism: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about commands and how to handle events using the MVVM design pattern: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

**Edit:**

If the command is defined in the view model, i.e. the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` itself, you should use a `RelativeSource` to be able to bind to it:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding}">
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDoubleClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
        </Image.InputBindings>
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Please, take a look at update section in original post to see what I did.

Comment: By the way, I use Prism.

Comment: See my edit. You should probably use a RelativeSource to bind to the command.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it is useful to handle `OnMouseDownClickCount` (or `MouseLeftButtonDown`) event handler and check `ClickCount` property of `MouseButtonEventArgs` argument. This approach allows to handle single-, double-, triple-clicks etc :)

```
private void OnMouseDownClickCount(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // Double Click occurred.
        ...
    }
}
```

But this approach has one "feature". While double-clicking `OnMouseDownClickCount` event rises two times: first with `e.ClickCount == 1` and then with `e.ClickCount == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @mm8 answers if you don't want to download prism, you can create a ICommand class like

```
namespace Lucid_Notes
{
  public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
  {
    public event EventHandler<object> Executed;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Executed != null)
            Executed(this, parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
  }
}
```

And use it as a Command:

```
<Image Source="sample-image.png">
  <Image.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick">
        <MouseBinding.Command>
            <local:SimpleCommand Executed="DoubleClickAction" />
      </MouseBinding.Command>
    </MouseBinding>
  </Image.InputBindings>
</Image>
```

Here, local representing the namespace where the class is present
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lucid_Notes"`. Finally add the function you want to execute on double click in the corresponding

```
  private void DoubleClickAction(object sender, object e)
  {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
  }
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601721/9794570 
 Example: https://github.com/ayush1920/Stackoverflow/tree/main/sample-Image-Click