# Binding button to function

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to bind button to function in "MVVM style".

I just started to convert my app to mvvm style.

my code:

**XAML** in `Page1.xaml` class:

```
 <Button x:Name="my_button" Content="Add"  Command="{Binding msgbox}"  Margin="451,82,39,0" Width="50" Height="31"/>
```

**ViewModelPage1.cs** class:

```
public class ViewModelPage6
    {
        public void msgbox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("mvvm is great");
        }     
    }
```

Can someone give a simpler answer then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531772/binding-button-click-to-a-method)

Thanks,

Flufy.

Comment: What is "hard" in linked answer?

Comment: usually all the logic isn't inside code behind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Bind a Command in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838884/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf)

Comment: With MVVM you will still have to create many classes containing code for converters, data template selectors, behaviors, etc. Just create reusable `ICommand` class once and then use it everywhere. I like [DelegateCommand](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html). "No code-behind" (pure mvvm) means avoiding code in the view. `ICommand` 
 implementation is viewmodel stuff.

Comment: as Sinatr said, you need to make use of `ICommand`. Make sure that you have also declared the datacontext of your `Page1.xaml` though. If it doesn't know that it is supposed to get data from `ViewModelPage1.cs` then it will never bind.

Comment: @Flufy : besides CodeBehind, I don't think there's a simpler way of binding a command into a VM when using MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example which binds a button:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Using icommand directly is a bit of a nuisance for most purposes, so you want to look into a framework which makes that easier.  The sample uses mvvmlight, other frameworks are available but this is a good one. Especially for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, I cant upvote because I don't have 15 rep :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a `method` to the `Command` property of a `Button` directly. You will have to use an implementation of `ICommand`.

This should get you started..

```
public ICommand msgboxCommand = new DelegateCommand(msgbox);

private void msgbox()
{
...
}
```

See this for more details: https://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

Besides, using a UI component like Messagebox in the ViewModel directly; isn't exactly MVVMish